# React: return an API result from a function with fetch and add to variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code example:

```
function getGameState() {
    return(fetch("http://localhost:8080/game_state"))
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data;
        });
};
```

I'm calling it from another function, like so:

```
function Game() {
    const gmState = getGameState()
    console.log(gmState);
}
```

The console output is as follows:

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

When I open up the arrow icon in the console, I see this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
available: null
board: Array(1)
0: {player: 1, x: 1, y: 0}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
player_turn: 2
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I need to pull the data from `player_turn` and `board` so I can pass those pieces to other functions.

The only examples I've found show console.log in the last `.then`, which I'm able to accomplish. I tried using `async` and `await` and many variations on this. I'm not able to find any working examples, and I'm starting to wonder if this sort of pattern is possible in React.

Answer (score 1):

Use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to fulfill the promises

```
async function Game() {
  const gmState = await getGameState()
  console.log(gmState);
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this, but this, once again, doesn't allow me to do anything but console.log. That's the issue I'm having. I can't do anything with it besides log. I want to pull the data out of it and do something with it. It is possible to organize code like this?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to assign the result to a variable in the other function. the result has data I need to pass to another function to use in it.